# Transfom a 2D numpy array into a same-size array containing positions at which an element is found in a 1D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 2 arrays, let's call them **Points** and **Line**.

**Points**  is a 2 dimensional array, with `Points.shape = (M, 3)`, such as:

```
Points = array([p1, q1, r1], 
               [p2, q2, r2],
               [p3, q3, r3],
                ...,          
               [pM, qM, rM])
```

p, q, r are integers, following no specific order, with each representing a particular point. For any specific row, all points p, q, r are different. But a particular integer can appear multiple times in *Points* (for example, q1 = p7 = p19 = r309 = 52106).

**Line**, on the other hand, is a 1D array, with `Line.shape = (N, )` such that `Line = array([l1, l2, l3, ..., lN])`. The terms `l` also represent integers like *Points*. Usually, `M` is much bigger than `N`.

Here is the problem : all integers in **Line** appear at least once in **Points**, but most p, q, r don't appear in **Line**. I want to construct a new 2D array **Points_index**, with the same shape as **Points**, such as :

- if the element in **Points** is also present in **Line**, return the position (index) of the element in **Line** (starting with 1, not 0).
- if not, return 0.

To illustrate, if :

```
Points = array([ 50,  156,   10],
               [  5,  509, 2225],
               [599, 1006,    1],
               [  1,    5,  156], 
               [ 50,  509,   47]) 

Line = array([50, 5, 156, 47])
```

then **Points_index** is :

```
array([1, 3, 0],  
      [2, 0, 0],  
      [0, 0, 0],  
      [0, 2, 3],  
      [1, 0, 4])
```

I want to this as fast as possible. I tried `in1d`, but it gives a True/False mask instead of the indexes. I have tried :

```
Points_index_123 = {}
for i in range(3):
    extr_i = np.zeros_like(Points[:, i])
    for k, el in enumerate(Points[:, i]):
        if el in Line:
            extr_i[k] = np.where(el == Line)[0]+1
        else:
            extr_i[k] = 0
    Points_index_123[i] = extr_i

Points_index = np.stack((Points_index_123[0], 
                         Points_index_123[1],
                         Points_index_123[2]), axis = 1)
```

But I feel that this is too slow (2 nested loops). Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import numpy as np
idx = np.zeros(Points.shape)
i, j, k = np.nonzero(Lines[:, None, None] == Points)
idx[j, k] = i + 1

idx
# array([[1., 3., 0.],
#        [2., 0., 0.],
#        [0., 0., 0.],
#        [0., 2., 3.],
#        [1., 0., 4.]])
```

Uses [broadcasted](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) comparison of each element in `Lines` with the `Points` array, followed by finding out `True` locations by [`np.nonzero()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) and then (fancy) [indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#indexing-multi-dimensional-arrays) the `idx` array to get their respective locations.

The +1 is added to `i` since you need the locations in `Lines` in 1-indexing.

Comment: Hello, I forgot to thank you for this method, which seems to be quite fast, and works perfectly. Thank you.